# Click anywhere to close this box

Tags: feature-request, design, voting

I got the message 'Welcome back! If you found this question useful,
don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.'
To my dismay, I had to click a tiny font instead of having the freedom to click anywhere on the box to close it.

I request allowing users to click anywhere on the box to close it.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. Does anyone have an idea of how this came to be and/or whether it still exists/is a problem?